# Is the gradient computation in the word2vec implementation actually wrong?

Tags: neural-networks, gradient

In the paper "Efficient Estimation of Word Representations in Vector Space", it is stated that "All models are trained using stochastic gradient descent and backpropagation":
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781.pdf  (at the beginning of page 3)

In the implementation of word2vec, the net output is referenced as f, and the gradient as g. In the case of hierarchical softmax, the target values are the binary values of the word code path. The transfer function is the logistic function. The calculation of the gradient (hs + skip gram):

```
// 'g' is the gradient multiplied by the learning rate
g = (1 - vocab[word].code[d] - f) * alpha;
```

( from https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/source/browse/trunk/word2vec.c#501 )

What I do not understand is why the derivative is missing here. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Finding_the_derivative_of_the_error or any textbook)

Shouldn't the calculation of the gradient be actually like this?

```
g = f*(1-f)*(1 - vocab[word].code[d] - f) * alpha;
```

Is this some kind of trick, am I missing something or is the implementation actually wrong? ( maybe the current implementation still works somehow, because the derivative just influences the magnitude of the gradient -  the sign of the gradient would still be correct).

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 2):

Alright. I got it. Somehow I missed that cross-entropy is used here as the error function instead of sum-of-squares. While the error signal according to the sum-of-squares function would actually be

```
g = f*(1-f)*(1 - vocab[word].code[d] - f) * alpha;
```

When using cross-entropy for classification, all the terms considering the zero-value targets cancel out and leave the astonishingly simple formula:

```
g = (1 - vocab[word].code[d] - f) * alpha;
```

Thus, the word2vec implementation is correct and I just missed something. A very good explanation on why the error signal computed for cross-entropy is so simple [can be found here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/neural-network-cross-entropy-error.aspx).